# Build variable $(DayOfYear) with preceding zeros?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

In VSTS (or TFS 2015) does the `$(DayOfYear)` build variable output with preceding zeros when under 100?

For example, would it output 063 or 63? Similarly, 003 or 3?

The reason I ask is because we use the following build number format:

> $(Major).$(Minor).$(Year:yy)$(DayOfYear)$(Rev:.rr)

Technically, without preceeding zeros, `1.0.16179.01` (a build from 27th June 2016) would be considered as a later build than `1.0.173.01` (a build on 3rd Jan 2017). With preceding zeros, this version number would be correctly represented as `1.0.17003.01`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$(DayOfYear) always output a number with XXX format. So you will get "003" or "063" with zero filled.

Comment: My assembly built from TFS 2015 disagrees with this answer